# Verifying the correctness of SSH-encrypted reverse VNC connection

Tags: ssh, vnc, tunnel

I set up an SSH encrypted reverse VNC connection to allow myself to remote into my parents' PC (running Ubuntu) when assistance is needed. A reverse VNC connection was necessary in this case for a number of reasons:

1. Parents' PC was behind a NAT – and I didn't want to set up port forwarding on their router.
2. My router has already been set up correctly for this to work.

Here's how I did it:

1. On (my) helpdesk PC (the PC that will control parents' PC), start `vncviewer` in listen mode:

   ```
   helpdeskpc:~$ vncviewer -listen
   Tue Aug 30 21:15:24 2011
   main:        Listening on port 5500
   ```
2. On parents' PC, run this command:

   ```
   noobpc:~$ ssh -t -L 5500:helpdeskpc:5500 localhost 'x11vnc -display :0 -connect helpdeskpc'
   ```

First of all, Have I correctly encrypted my reverse VNC connection?

If so, here is the more interesting question: Being a paranoid person, how can I prove to myself that the VNC connection is indeed going through the SSH tunnel? I can't make heads/tails of the `netstat` output.

What other tools can I use to verify that the VNC connection is using the SSH tunnel correctly?

Comment: TeamViewer does basically the same thing but with a lot less hassle and a couple more guarantees than VNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, **you're not encrypting at all**.

No matter what other options you specify,

```
ssh localhost
```

creates an encrypted connection the *local* machine. The command you execute doesn't know anything about that, and connects itself to helpdeskpc. Instead, you want

```
noobpc$ ssh -L 5500:localhost:5500 helpdeskpc
```

Then, in a different terminal (or after detaching ssh):

```
noobpc$ x11vnc -display :0 -connect localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error phihag! The netstat output makes a little bit more sense now.